# Limiting input range of integer in QTableWidget column

Tags: c++, qt, qtablewidget

I am writing a table using QTableWidget. How can I limit the range of input (to 0 r 1 for example) in one particular column of the table?

Is delegating the only option?

Comment: You can add a spin boxes for cells you want to limit the input for.

Comment: @vahancho  thanks for the comment! How do you include the spinbox inside the table? I tried without success. The spinbox ends up outside the table.

Comment: I am trying this:

https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qtwidgets-itemviews-spinboxdelegate-example.html

https://code.qt.io/cgit/qt/qtbase.git/tree/examples/widgets/itemviews/spinboxdelegate?h=5.14